# Where does a Java ME JAR install to?

Tags: deployment, java-me, installation, jar

When you install a Java ME program on a phone using a .jar file, where does it install to? At which path can the Java files be found? Or does it install to a location hidden from the filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact location of your application's files will depend on device/platform your running on. As far as I know there is no standard way for an application to get this location.

This is deliberate - there should be no reason for you application to be aware of how/where it is stored (doing so would prevent portability).

If you just want access to other resources stored in your JAR I suggest you look a the `getResourceAsStream` method of the `MIDP` Class class ([see javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))). For example:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("somefile.txt");
```

Or, assuming your target devices support it, there is [JSR-75](http://java.sun.com/javame/technology/msa/jsr75.jsp) which provides a File Connection package to allow access to the device's filesystem directly.